# Do not see an option to debug a Windows Phone Application?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, windows-phone

I installed Windows SDK before and there was an option showing up in Visual Studio to test an application by debugging. I had to reinstall the SDK again but the only Option I was seeing was Start instead of any other WVGA OR WXGA simulator. Is there anyway I can fix this? Hyper-V option is also enabled and I am using 2011 Macbook Air 13.3"

Answer (score 0):

If the options you refer to are the ones in the Visual Studio menu with the green arrow, it only shows the options for the `StartUp` project (the one which is bold in the Solution Explorer).

If you set your Windows Phone project as StartUp project (right click on the project, and select "Set as `StartUp` project"), you will see the mentioned emulator options on the menu.

Other option is to right click on the project, select `Properties`, and in the `Debug` tab, select the desired `Target Device`.